# WScript.Shell Fails For Unknown Reasons VB6.5

Tags: vba

In VBA I am running a piece of external software I wrote.  I know the software works well.  I can run it from the command line.  But when I attempt to execute it using WScript.Shell.Run, it returns a 1 and it never runs.  I can't even tell that it executes the software at all.

Here is the executing portion of the VBA class.

```
Public Function Execute() As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim exitCode As Integer: exitCode = -1

    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'Run program with arguments and wait for the program to finish 
    If Me.PrinterType = 1 Then exitCode = wsh.Run(Me.Path & " /serial=" & Me.SerialNumber & " /position=" & Me.Location & "", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
    If Me.PrinterType = 2 Then exitCode = wsh.Run(Me.Path & " /boxid=" & Me.Location & " /version=" & Me.Version, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
    Execute = exitCode

End Function
```

An example of the full execute string:

> C:.path.to.\PrintLabel.exe /serial=EOSJ61110044 /position=2

Evidence that the script runs without error from the same machine the VBA is executing on:
[image]

So I've got no idea what's going on.

I can use the following [VBA Shell function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) successfully:

```
If Me.PrinterType = 1 Then exitCode = Shell(Me.Path & " /serial=" & Me.SerialNumber & " /position=" & Me.Location, vbHide)
```

But the problem then becomes that the VBA doesn't wait on the software to finish before continuing.  So I need to continue to try and make `WScript.Shell` work.  What am I missing?  Are there any specific references that need to be enabled that I could be missing?

Update 1:

Tried this to mimic this SO post, but still didn't have success:

```
If Me.PrinterType = 1 Then fullExecutionString = Me.Path & " /serial=" & Me.SerialNumber & " /position=" & Me.Location
If Me.PrinterType = 2 Then fullExecutionString = Me.Path & " /boxid=" & Me.Location & " /version=" & Me.Version
wsh.Run fullExecutionString, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Update 2:
Made a small method that repeats the process in windows cmd console.  It works (more or less) with the same code.  I am guessing it has something to do with the command path string with arguments?

```
Private Sub Button2_Released()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim exitCode As Integer: exitCode = 0
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    exitCode = wsh.Run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

After much debugging I resolved that the path with spaces is causing the issue.  If I directly input the following (notice the quote placement), the code successfully runs:

```
exitCode = wsh.Run("""C:\path.to\PrintLabel.exe"" /serial=EOSJ61110044 /position=2", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

So in the end I adjusted my `Path` property:

```
Public Property Let Path(ByVal NewValue As String)
   actPath = Chr(34) & NewValue & Chr(34)
End Property
Public Property Get Path() As String
    Path = actPath
End Property
```